# Basic assistance Arrays and LinkedLists

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, int

i am fairly new to java so was wondering if i could get some basic help.

I have a class called Timetable

```
public class Timetable
{   private String Month;
    private String Day;
    private int[] times;

public Timetable(String month, String Day, int[] times) 
    {
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        //initalize various times..
```

This class relates to another class(LinkedList) of Timetables that adds the month,day and times. like this..

```
Add(new Timetable("May","Monday", **???**));
```

now i need to add the times that are in an array and vary such as {1,2,3,4} or {2,4,9} and there are only int[4] indexes.

Any Suggestions of how i initialize the times and pass the int[] times to the create the timetable??

Comment: upvote for awesome stack overflow username xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to the other answers you could also adapt your constructor signature to

```
public Timetable(String month, String Day, int... times) { /*...*/ }
```

The usage within your Timetable class would remain the same (the `int...` argument is mapped to an array of `int`s) but the advantage would be that the calls would be simplified to

```
LinkedList<Timetable> link = new LinkedList<Timetable>();

link.add(new Timetable("May", "Monday", 1, 2, 3, 4)); // array creation is now optional
link.add(new Timetable("May", "Monday", new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4})); // works as well
link.add(new Timetable("June", "Sunday", 5, 6, 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would initialize the array just before calling the Add method:

```
int[] times = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Add(new Timetable("May", "Monday", times));
```

or:

```
int[] times = {5, 6, 7};
Add(new Timetable("May", "Monday", times));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the times like this one too:

```
LinkedList<Timetable> link = new LinkedList<Timetable>();

link.add(new Timetable("May", "Monday", new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
link.add(new Timetable("June", "Sunday", new int[]{5, 6, 7}));
```